# Why can't Hibernate load a class in my JAR file, declared in the hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: hibernate, maven, classnotfoundexception, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using Hibernate 4.0.1.Final.  I'm using the Assemby plugin to include all my dependencies in my JAR project.  However, Hibernate is having trouble finding one of my classes, and it appears correctly spelled.  In my hibernate.cfg.xml file (located at the root of my JAR), I have

```
<mapping class="com.myco.fdr.myproject.model.UserRole" />
```

I load the file like so

```
final Configuration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();  
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

But when the above code is executed, I get this exception …

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myco.model.UserRole"/> in the configuration:
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:87)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:130)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.localInvoke(MessagingContainer.java:249)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.delivery(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:268)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.invoke(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:138)
    at $Proxy84.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.quartz.inflow.QuartzJob.execute(QuartzJob.java:57)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myco.model.UserRole"/> in the configuration:
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1555)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1534)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
    at org.cbco.subco.dido.service.AbstractServiceProvider.getSessionFactory(AbstractServiceProvider.java:66)
    at org.cbco.subco.dido.service.AbstractServiceProvider.initServices(AbstractServiceProvider.java:118)
    at org.cbco.subco.dido.quartz.ProcessOrdersJob.execute(ProcessOrdersJob.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: com.mainco.fdr.myco.model.UserRole
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:542)
    ... 31 more
```

The class in question appears at the root of my JAR file (Maybe it should appear in a "classes" directory?).  Anyway, here is how I use the Assembler plugin …

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How do I resolve this ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: Is it a typo or have you misspelt the classname in `hibernate-cfg.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `persistence.xml`?
Add to your `persistence.xml`  property

```
 <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: @Ilya what was an exact content of your persistence.xml ?

Comment: @MrPhi http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch01s02s01.html